# How to copy/add files in user's home directory in host to container's home directory?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

## # Update

I just realized that ADD/COPY command doesn't permit any access
to files or directories outside of current working directory in host.
One more thing is that if you specify an absolute path of file/directory
as a source path after ADD/COPY command, it'll also not be permitted.

Please refer to this and have happy hacking ! :)

=======================================================================

I would like to copy/add files under a user's home directory in host
into the container's home directory for the same user.

First of all, a user can be changed as the user who is building a docker image with Dockerfile on each host. For instance, in my host, I have a user "test". In the other person's host, there will be a user "newbie". In each host, my Dockerfile will be built/used.

The following is my test syntax for copying/adding files.

```
...
RUN mkdir -p /home/${USER}/.ssh

ADD /home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa* /home/${USER}/.ssh/
or COPY /home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa* /home/${USER}/.ssh/ 
...
```

When I try to build this Docker file, the following error is displayed.

```
Step 43/44 : ADD /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa* /home/${USER}/.ssh/
No source files were specified
```

Please kindly guide me to do what I want to do. :)
Thanks.

Comment: Actually, what I would like to know exactly is...how to specify host's user's home directory in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

It has now been two years sice the question has been ask, but I want to cite to official documentation here which states the same as what @Sung-Jin Park already found out.

> ADD obeys the following rules:
>
> - The  path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot ADD
>     ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is
>     to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker
>     daemon.

[Dockerfile reference ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to accomplish the end goal is to first create a symlink for the file you want copied from outside of the build directory into the build directory.

```
# build/.gitignore
private/
```

```
# build/
mkdir private
ln $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa private/id_rsa
```

```
# build/Dockerfile
RUN mkdir -p /home/${USER}/.ssh

ADD /home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa* /home/${USER}/.ssh/
or COPY /home/${USER}/.ssh/id_rsa* /home/${USER}/.ssh/
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use the following:

`WORKDIR /home
COPY ${pwd}/my-file.txt .`